# Алгоритм поиска дубликатов файлов

Tags: алгоритм, файловая-система

Меня интересуют алгоритмы поиска дубликатов файлов: среди множества каталогов нужно найти и запомнить все файлы с одинаковым содержимым. В связи с большими объемами данных для обработки требуется хороший алгоритм, советы и рекомендации насчет возможной оптимизации его работы и т.п.

Я не прошу предоставить мне кусок готового кода или каким-либо иным способом полностью реализованное задание, буду благодарен за любую полученную ценную информацию относительно данного вопроса.

Comment: имхо лучше воспользоватся готовым решением, в противном случае попахивает изобретением велосипеда. найдите любую утилиту для командной строки и запускайте ее из своей программы.

Comment: @jmu, а есть готовое решение, которое ещё и одинаковые папки найдёт?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот решение в-лоб:

1. Обходим все каталоги рекурсивно, сохраняем (path, filesize) в таблицу базы данных.
2. Сортируем собранную таблицу по filesize, делаем выборку по всем записям где filesize неуникально.
3. Для каждой пачки файлов с одинаковым filesize вычисляем хеш, проверяем на равенство.
4. ???
5. PROFIT

Comment: сдается мне что читать байты до первого несоответствия быстрее хеша будет, хотя для пачки не знаю как по затратам если она большая

Comment: Здесь еще нужно глубже понять статистику дубликатов, откуда и почему они берутся, где теоретически могут появится, какой их средний размер, чтобы ускорить первый и второй пункт.

Comment: @aknew Не думаю, что так уж много файлов с одинаковым размером, чтобы думать о скорости подсчета хэша.

Comment: ну как бы если файлы большого размера, то это может быть весьма критично, хотя все конечно зависит от задачи

Comment: Можно считать очень простой хэш.

Например в [FNV](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) для каждого символа делается одно умножение и один XOR. 

 Для **очень больших** файлов можно считать хэш по некоторым блокам файла (допустим суммарно до 1MB).


И уже для файлов с одинаковым хэшем делать cmp.

Comment: Преимущество хэша в том, что он считается всего один раз. Если им пренебречь и сравнивать файлы напрямую, то получится как раз та самая ситуация, в которой комбинаторика рано или поздно обязательно побеждает человека. Причём в данном случае скорее рано, чем поздно.

Answer (score 4):

[fdupes](http://premium.caribe.net/~adrian2/fdupes.html) не смотрели? У него есть такой алгоритм и он вроде уже проверен временем

Answer (score 3):

[Здесь](http://www.clonespy.com/?News) какие-то люди уже 10 лет публикуют такое Windows приложение. Может Вам стоит связаться с ними.

Comment: В Тотал Командере кстати встроенный поиск дубликатов. Очень удобно.

Answer (score 1):

Hash для всего файла считать - плохая идея, если есть большие файлы

Я сделал так:
Для группы файлов с одинаковым размером делишь на группы по первого очередного байта в файле, для групп размером > 1 читаешь следующий байт и так по рекурсии
Естественно, считывание байт должно быть буфферизованно, для каждого файла считываешь блоки в неск. килобайт, пототом оттуда выбираешь побайтно